# Getting progress events from WiX Deployment Tools Foundation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, dtf

How can I get install progress events using the WiX Deployment Tools Foundation `Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Installer.InstallProduct()`?

I do not want any kind of UI, just an event that I can handle. I see references to the `InstallMessage` enum, which has a `Progress` member, but I'd like to see an example of its usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call Installer.EnableLog with InstallLogModes.Progress and Installer.SetExternalUI before Installer.InstallProduct. The delegate gets messages including InstallMessage.Progress.

Answer (score 2):

Download the source to WiX and look in the src/DTF/Samples/EnbeddedUI project.

Comment: Doesn't that imply a UI? Can I handle the events without a UI?

Comment: You should be able to process the messages without a UI.

Comment: Stupid question, but how can I execute that EmbeddedUI sample? It looks like it's just a class library, and nothing in DTF.sln references it.